# Count the consecutive zero bits (trailing) on the right in parallel: an explanation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, bit-manipulation

Consider [this link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZerosOnRightParallel) from the Bit Twiddling Hacks website.
In order to count the trailing bits, the following algorithm is used:

```
unsigned int v;      // 32-bit word input to count zero bits on right
unsigned int c = 32; // c will be the number of zero bits on the right
v &= -signed(v); /* THIS LINE */
if (v) c--;
if (v & 0x0000FFFF) c -= 16;
if (v & 0x00FF00FF) c -= 8;
if (v & 0x0F0F0F0F) c -= 4;
if (v & 0x33333333) c -= 2;
if (v & 0x55555555) c -= 1;
```

Can someone explain me the role of the line marked as `/* THIS LINE */` and more importantly is it possible to use only bitwise operations to avoid the use of `signed()` ?

EDIT: How to replace `signed()` by arithmetic/logical/bitwise operations?

Comment: *signed* is just a type conversion, it does not represent any actual assembly instruction.

Comment: Not on any CPU produced in this century, no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v &= -signed(v)` will clear all but the lowest set bit (`1`-bit) of v, i.e. extracts the least significant 1 bit from v (v will become a number with power of 2 afterwards). For example, for `v=14 (1110)`, after this, we have `v=2 (0010)`.

Here, using `signed()` is because v is `unsigned` and you're trying to negate an `unsigned` value (gives compilation error with VS2012) (comment from JoelRondeau). Or you will get a warning like this: *`warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned`* (my test).

Comment: signed() is because v is unsigned and you're trying to negate an unsigned value (gives compilation error with VS2012).

Comment: @JoelRondeau Updated as you said. Thanks.

Comment: @herohuyongtao: but assuming that I do not have a signed() function, how do I do that using only standard operations (arithmetic/logical/bitwise operators)?

Comment: @JoelRondeau I just tested under VS2012, it works ok with warning shown in the updated answer. What did I miss?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Going to guess I have my project settings to compile "warnings as errors". If that's not the reason, I'll let you know.

Comment: @herohuyongtao What does -signed(v) do ? does it take two's complement

Answer (score 0):

The expression `v &= -signed(v)`, is ANDing the the number and the negative of that number itself. So we are performing a binary AND on the number and the two's complement representation of the number

Answer (score 0):

Following what i understood from the code :-

AND v with its 2's complement :- sets all digits after the first 1 from right to 0

> Example :- v = 10101000 then -v = ~v + 1    (1's complement plus 1) =
>   01010111 + 1 =01011000
>   v&-v = 10101000 & 01011000 = 00001000

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple bitwise operation to do `-signed(v)`. Addition and subtraction require "carries", operations on bit X may affect bit X+1. So, it takes arithmetic.

But basically, unary `-x` is just binary `0-x`, so you can use standard arithmetic if you don't have a direct negation operation.

Comment: > There's no simple bitwise operation to do -signed(v) There is. (v & 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1

Answer (score 0):

`signed` in this code is an error which causes undefined behavior.

It can be safely removed.  The code requires the behavior of unsigned negation... which `signed` negation may or may not deliver.  Without the keyword the behavior is always as expected.

Now, the code still is not portable.  But at least it will be safe, and it will work if `int` is 32 bits.